# Weird recursion outputs just looking for light in my state of darkness right now

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

So my goal is to create a recursive function that checks whether a is a subvector of b.  I realize that what I have right now would only cover 2 base cases if `a` is larger then `b` return false and if they both match from the start so vector A would look like `a[1,2,3]` and `b[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Anyway I'm wondering why I am getting very strange outputs and what exactly is going on, I am completely stumped as to what is actually going on.

```
bool recursive_sub_vector(vector<int>& a, vector<int> b, size_t k) {
    int i = k;
    int size = a.size();
    vector<int>& va = a;
    vector<int> vb = b;
    if (va.size() > vb.size()) {
        cout << "here 1" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    if (i < va.size() && va.at(i) == vb.at(i)) {
        cout << "I=" << i << " VA size= " << va.size() << endl;

        // i++;  <--If this is uncommented and the other ++ commented it will
        // enter this
        // if statement and cout "hit return" but then proceed exactly like it
        // did.

        if (i == size) {
            cout << "hit return" << endl;
            return true;
        }
        i++ recursive_sub_vector(va, vb, i);
        cout << "it should not be able to go here" << endl;
    }

    cout << "I=" << i << " VA size= " << va.size() << endl;
    cout << "here 4" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

So here is what it outputs!

```
I=0 VA size= 3
I=1 VA size= 3
I=2 VA size= 3
I=3 VA size= 3
here 4
it should not be able to go here
I=3 VA size= 3
here 4
it should not be able to go here
I=2 VA size= 3
here 4
it should not be able to go here
I=1 VA size= 3
here 4
0
```

I'm curious as to why it does not enter that if statement to return true when the value outputs as `3`.  Even when hardcoded as `1, 2 or 3` it won't enter it.

But when I uncomment that `i++` before the if statement it will output but not return.

I'm also curious as to how the hell it can possibly get to that `cout<<"it should not be able to go here"` and why i starts to decrease in value when I have that literally nowhere in the code!

Also if possible I'd love some insight as to where to go from here, I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and am getting nowhere into an algorithm for how to solve the problem as a whole.
I have it done through iteration but cannot mentally get it recursively.  I cannot change the function parameters or have any outside variables. Pretty much just need to check if vector a is a subvector of `b` so `a=[1,2,3]` `b=[2,5,1,2,3,6]` would return true, `a=[1,2,3]` `b=[1,2,4,5,3,2,3]` would return false they need to be in sequential order.  Very easily done through iteration.

Anyone who actually read through this I send you my thanks and to anyone who answers and takes time out of their day to help me with my problem I seriously appreciate the insight!  Thank you for helping out a coding peasant such as myself haha!

Comment: You call your function recursively without returning what it returned to your recursive call.

Comment: "looking for light in my state of darkness right now" - sounds like someone's in need of some alcohol to me :-)

Comment: @jxh DOH!  Hahaha I feel like a fool!  That fully fixed it man thank you!